# Install/uninstall ios app programmatically from Mac app

Tags: ios, macos, usb, installation, uninstallation

I want to create .ipa installer/uninstaller app for mac like itunes.
How to install/uninstall ios app from mac app using USB like itunes application.

Any help will be appreciated.